# SQL Server merge and pk violation

Tags: sql-server, merge, primary-key

I'm trying to understand why in a scenario like the following

```
DECLARE @source TABLE 
             (
                 orderId NVARCHAR(50),
                 customerId NVARCHAR(50)
             )

DECLARE @target TABLE 
             (
                  orderId NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
                  customerId NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
             )

INSERT INTO @source 
VALUES ('test', '123'), ('test', '234')

MERGE @target AS TRG
USING (SELECT DISTINCT orderId, customerId
       FROM @source) AS SRC ON SRC.orderId = TRG.orderId

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TRG.customerId = SRC.customerId

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (orderId, customerId)
    VALUES (orderId, customerId);
```

I'm getting a duplicate key violation error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 21
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#B3D7759__0809335D4BE1521F'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@target'. The duplicate key value is (test).

What I expect is that the update statement finds the existing key and updates the customerId so that at the end I have in @target 1 row with orderId = 'test' and customerId = '234'.

For what I can assume, it instead tries to insert all records as it first doesn't find any key match at the beginning of the merge, causing the violation as the source contains the key multiple times.

Is this right? Is there any way to achieve what I am expecting using the merge function?

---

***@user1443098***

I've read your link, thanks. However I have a massive data insertion coming from a source table and going into 10 different tables; I tried to implement the procedure with a cursor and it took like 0.5s per record (with all the if exists statements). With merge statement, 300 rows have been inserted in the 10 different tables in less than one sec. So in my case it does a lot of difference in performance terms.

Comment: There are many issues with MERGE.  See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/  including key violations.  I try not to use it

Comment: `@trg` starts out empty, so all of the rows in `@src` will hit the `NOT MATCHED` and you end up with two rows each with `orderId` `test`. `MERGE` cannot touch rows twice -- or rather, it can, but whenever you've written a `MERGE` that can potentially do that the results are nondeterministic and may error out. I agree with the right honorable 1443098 that `MERGE` should generally be avoided if the equivalent sequence of `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s is not too hard to write.

Comment: Considering that `OrderID` is the PK, and that's what you're matching on, what is `UPDATE SET TRG.orderId = SRC.orderId` trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: a really good question!

Comment: Also, from the name `@trg`, is it too presumptuous to assume this table will be filled by or otherwise involved in a trigger? Triggers are extra hard to get right, so avoid cleverness like `MERGE` in them like the plague.

Comment: @Larnu sorry, wrote down the code on a hurry. I fixed it now...this isn't affecting the error anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `@trg` stands for target, `@src` stands for source

Comment: Oh thank goodness, that's one concern less. Forget I said that, except don't, in case you do ever find yourself in a trigger some day. :-) (But do consider just writing `@target` and `@source` -- there is no tax on identifier length and a future maintainer may appreciate it. That future maintainer might even be you.)

Comment: @user1443098 I've updated the question with a clarification for you

Comment: @JeroenMostert no problem, you are right...unfortunately I often shorten everything :)

Comment: Re: Performance.  Under ideal circumstances, MERGE *may* outperform an upsert,  OTOH the issues and problems (like the one you found), can be a downer.  Why we have to choose between performance and correctness in cases like this is beyond me, but there you have it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two records in `@source` with the same `OrderID`.  There is not a match for either record in `@target` so the `NOT MATCHED` clause is trying to insert both of these records.  But it can not do this because the primary key on `OrderID` in the `@target` table requires that all inserted records have unique values for `OrderID`.  The duplication of values into the primary key causes the primary key violation.

If you are expecting duplicates are possible in the source... you should eliminate them in your `USING` sub-query.  Something like this:

```
(SELECT orderId, max(customerId) customerId
FROM @source
group by orderId)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so that's how I've assumed. I was hoping the statement was designed to handle this cases. That's really a shame because I've found it very good under the performance aspect.

Comment: You can eliminate the possibility of duplicates in your source... I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Yes thanks, I was thinking to do something on the source. The downside is that I have to forecast all passible key violations in advance and treat them.